# How can i use arduino Serial.begin() with rx only

Tags: arduino

Can we use serial communication in *arduino* only for *RX* pin,so that i am free to use pin *1(TX)* as digital *I/O*:

```
Serial.write('a');
pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
```